# converting NULL to numeric and taking the sum of lists

Tags: r, list, dplyr, null, tidyverse

I have a BTO dataset, which I converted from long to wide format to prepare it for diversity measurements using the `diversity` function from the `vegan` package.

To achieve this I used this code:

```
diversity <- pivot_wider(bird_case, names_from = ENGLISH_NAME, values_from = HOW_MANY)
```

The results comes up with list elements as I converted the months into seasons with a previous code. I wish to take the sums of all the lists, so only a single sum remains in each cell. As for the NULL values I want these converted to 0.

I have tried to replace the NULL values to zero using this

```
diversity[diversity == "NULL"] <- 0
```

it won't work.

As for converting the list elements and taking the sum, I have tried aggregate to no avail.

Heres a reproducible code:

```
structure(list(year = c(2018, 2019, 2017, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2017, 
2017, 2016, 2019, 2018, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2017, 
2015, 2018, 2015, 2017, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2018, 2018, 2017, 
2014, 2015, 2017, 2014, 2014, 2017, 2019, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2012, 
2019, 2012, 2013, 2019, 2017, 2011, 2017, 2016, 2016, 2010), 
    Season = c("Winter", "Winter", "Summer", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Autumn", "Autumn", "Winter", "Spring", "Autumn", "Spring", 
    "Winter", "Summer", "Autumn", "Summer", "Spring", "Summer", 
    "Spring", "Spring", "Autumn", "Summer", "Summer", "Autumn", 
    "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter", "Spring", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Summer", "Winter", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Winter", "Spring", 
    "Winter", "Summer", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Winter", "Autumn", 
    "Winter", "Spring", "Winter"), POSTCODE = c("NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", 
    "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", 
    "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", 
    "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", 
    "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", "NR29 5QA", "NR15 1TS", 
    "NR15 1TS", "NR15 1TS", "NR15 1TS", "NR15 1TS", "NR15 1TS", 
    "NR15 1TS", "NR15 1TS", "NR15 1TS", "NR15 1TS", "NR15 1TS", 
    "NR15 1TS", "NR15 1TS", "NR15 1TS", "NR15 1TS", "PE32 1TL", 
    "PE32 1TL", "PE32 1TL", "PE32 1TL", "PE32 1TL", "PE32 1TL", 
    "PE32 1TL", "PE32 1TL", "PE32 1TL", "PE32 1TL", "PE32 1TL", 
    "PE32 1TL", "PE32 1TL", "PE32 1TL"), LOC_ID = c("LOC568364", 
    "LOC568364", "LOC568364", "LOC568364", "LOC568364", "LOC568364", 
    "LOC568364", "LOC568364", "LOC568364", "LOC568364", "LOC568364", 
    "LOC568364", "LOC568364", "LOC568364", "LOC568364", "LOC568364", 
    "LOC568364", "LOC568364", "LOC568364", "LOC568364", "LOC568364", 
    "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", 
    "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", 
    "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", 
    "LOC569508", "LOC569508", "LOC569508", "LOC569508", "LOC569508", 
    "LOC569508", "LOC569508", "LOC569508", "LOC569508", "LOC569508", 
    "LOC569508", "LOC569508", "LOC569508", "LOC569508"), Wren = list(
        c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 1, c(1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 
        1, 3, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), c(1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), c(2, 1, 2, 3, 
        1, 1, 1), c(1, 1), c(1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 
        1), c(1, 1), c(1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
        NULL, 1, c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1), NULL, NULL, c(1, 1, 1), NULL, 
        1, NULL, NULL, c(1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 
        1, 1), c(1, 1), NULL, NULL, c(1, 1), 1, c(1, 1, 1), NULL, 
        c(1, 1, 1, 1)), Dunnock = list(c(2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 2), c(2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1), c(1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2), 
        c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1), 2, c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
        2), c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 
        2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2), c(2, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
        1), c(2, 1, 1, 2, 2), c(3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2), c(1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(1, 1, 2, 1, 
        2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), c(3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 2), c(2, 2, 
        2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2), c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1), 
        c(2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 1, 
        2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 
        2, 1, 1), c(3, 4, 6, 3, 3, 3), c(1, 1, 2, 1), c(2, 1), 
        c(2, 2, 1, 2, 1), c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2), c(2, 2), c(1, 
        1, 1, 2), c(2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2), 2, c(2, 2, 
        3, 2, 2), c(2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 1, NULL, c(3, 2), c(1, 
        1), c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(3, 
        3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 
        2, 1, 1), c(3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), c(3, 3, 1, 1, 
        1, 3, 2, 1), c(1, 1, 2, 1), c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
        2, 2, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), 
        c(1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 
        1, 2, 1, 1)), `Blue Tit` = list(c(1, 1, 2, 3), c(2, 2, 
    3, 2, 2), 4, c(4, 2, 3, 4), 2, c(2, 2), c(1, 2, 2), c(2, 
    2), c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2), NULL, c(2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
        c(2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2), 2, NULL, 7, c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
        2, 2, 2), NULL, c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(4, 2, 4, 3, 
        7, 3, 2), 1, c(2, 2, 3), c(8, 10, 10, 12, 10, 8, 5, 12
        ), c(6, 4, 4, 6, 4), c(12, 6, 6, 6, 6), c(4, 4, 5, 5, 
        8), c(10, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4), 4, c(10, 4, 4, 8, 6), c(4, 
        6, 4, 10, 6, 6, 8, 7, 6), c(12, 12, 6), c(12, 8, 12, 
        12, 12, 10, 10), c(10, 5, 10, 5, 10), c(12, 12, 6), c(6, 
        6), c(4, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 6), c(3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), c(2, 
        2, 2, 1, 2, 1), c(2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), c(4, 3, 
        1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4), c(2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2), c(2, 
        4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3), c(3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2), c(1, 
        2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2), c(5, 3, 9, 4, 4, 3, 9, 5), c(1, 
        2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2), c(4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 
        3, 4, 5, 2), c(3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3), c(2, 
        2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4), c(2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
        1)), `Pied/White Wagtail` = list(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, c(2, 2, 2, 2), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
        c(2, 2, 2, 1), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), NULL, c(2, 
        2), NULL, c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
        2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3), c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
        NULL, c(1, 1), 1, 1, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        1, NULL, 1, c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(2, 1, 2, 1), c(1, 1), 
        c(1, 1), 1, 1, 1, 1, c(1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1)), `Collared Dove` = list(
        c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
        3, 2, 2), c(2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), c(1, 1, 2, 2), 
        NULL, c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
        3), c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
        2), c(2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 22, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
        c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
        2), c(2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
        3, 3, 3, 3, 2), c(2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), 
        c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
        1), c(1, 1), c(1, 1), c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1), c(2, 2, 1, 2), 
        2, c(2, 1), c(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), NULL, c(2, 1, 1), 
        c(2, 2), 1, 1, c(2, 2), NULL, c(9, 9, 17, 8, 19), c(6, 
        3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3), c(16, 9, 12, 3, 7, 5), c(4, 4, 3, 
        3, 5, 3, 2), c(2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 3, 
        4, 4, 2, 12, 3, 5, 4), c(2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3), 
        c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3), c(4, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 3), 
        c(3, 1, 12, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 12), c(3, 2, 1, 5, 3, 2, 
        2, 1, 2, 3, 2), c(3, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 10), c(2, 2, 
        1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2), c(6, 2, 6, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 4, 11, 
        3, 2)), `Great Tit` = list(c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
        c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1), NULL, c(1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 
        4, 1), NULL, c(1, 2, 1, 1), c(1, 1), NULL, c(1, 1, 1, 
        2, 1, 1), 1, c(1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1), 1, NULL, c(2, 2, 
        1, 1), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 1, 3, c(2, 2, 
        2, 1), c(4, 2, 1, 2), c(2, 1), c(8, 8, 12, 6, 8), c(2, 
        2, 3, 2), c(8, 3, 6, 4, 6), c(2, 2, 4, 2), c(1, 1, 2), 
        c(2, 2, 2), c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
        2), c(4, 4, 6), c(2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2), c(3, 4, 2, 2, 
        3), 6, c(2, 2), c(1, 2), 2, c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), c(1, 
        1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), c(2, 2, 
        3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3), c(3, 1, 1, 2), c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
        2, 2, 1, 2), c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), c(2, 1, 2, 1), c(2, 
        3, 2, 3, 2, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1), c(1, 2, 2, 1, 
        1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
        2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 8, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)), Robin = list(c(1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 
    1, 3, 3, 2), c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2), c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 
    1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), 1, c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 1), c(2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 2), c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3), c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), c(1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1), c(2, 2, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2), c(2, 2, 6, 
    1, 1, 2), c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), c(1, 3, 3, 3), c(3, 
    1, 1, 2), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2), c(2, 
    1, 2, 1, 3), c(2, 2), c(3, 1, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(3, 
    4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2), 1, c(4, 2, 4, 2, 4), c(1, 1, 3), 
        c(2, 2, 2), 2, c(3, 2, 2), c(1, 2), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
        c(3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1), c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 
        1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1), 
        c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(2, 4, 3, 
        2, 1, 6, 2, 3, 1, 2), c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1), 
        c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1), c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
        1, 1, 2)), Greenfinch = list(2, c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
    ), 1, c(1, 1, 2), NULL, NULL, NULL, c(2, 2, 2), c(3, 1, 2, 
    3, 3), 2, c(2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2), NULL, c(2, 1, 
    3, 2), NULL, c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1), c(2, 2), 2, 1, c(2, 2, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), NULL, c(3, 1, 3), c(4, 2, 4), 1, 
        c(2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 
        2, 3, 2, 3), c(3, 1), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3), c(2, 6, 4, 2, 
        2, 2), 4, c(5, 5, 5, 5), c(2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 4), 4, c(2, 
        2), c(4, 1, 4), 2, c(7, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3), c(4, 
        3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), c(6, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2), c(3, 1, 2, 
        3), 1, c(1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1), c(1, 2, 2, 
        2, 3, 1, 3), c(1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1), c(1, 4, 1, 3, 4), 
        c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1), c(2, 2, 5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1), c(7, 2, 
        6, 1, 2), c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1), c(4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1)), `House Sparrow` = list(
        NULL, c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), NULL, c(2, 2, 4, 6, 3, 4, 
        3, 3), 3, c(3, 2, 2, 2), NULL, NULL, NULL, c(2, 2, 2), 
        c(1, 2, 2), c(2, 2), NULL, NULL, c(3, 5), c(2, 2, 2, 
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2), NULL, NULL, c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 
        3, 3), NULL, c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, c(20, 14, 12, 10, 8, 14, 21), c(6, 5, 9, 
        9, 9, 6), c(13, 12, 5, 21, 11, 12, 16, 10, 15), c(3, 
        2, 7, 3, 1), c(10, 11, 15, 8, 12, 15, 5, 16), c(1, 5, 
        5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 6, 4, 4), c(2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 7, 7, 
        3, 5, 3), c(9, 10, 10, 7, 8, 10, 10, 6, 8, 6, 12, 9), 
        c(10, 5, 13, 14, 4, 5, 9, 9, 10, 8, 9), c(10, 9, 10, 
        7, 9, 10, 8, 7, 9, 14), c(3, 7, 5, 10, 2, 6, 14, 6, 3, 
        7, 3), c(7, 9, 11, 5, 5, 7, 7, 6, 6, 10, 5, 7, 16), c(5, 
        7, 5, 5, 6, 8, 7, 4, 5), c(15, 10, 12, 9, 3, 9, 10, 11
        )), `Coal Tit` = list(1, c(1, 1, 1), NULL, c(2, 3, 2, 
    2, 4, 2, 2), NULL, 2, NULL, NULL, c(1, 1, 1), NULL, c(2, 
    1), 1, 1, NULL, 2, NULL, 1, NULL, 2, 1, 2, c(1, 1, 1), c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 
    2), 1, c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2), c(2, 
    2), c(2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2), 2, 
        c(1, 1), NULL, 1, NULL, c(1, 1, 1), c(2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
        1, 1, 3, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1), c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), c(1, 
        1, 1, 2, 1, 1), NULL, c(2, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1), c(1, 2, 
        1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 1), Woodpigeon = list(c(2, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3), c(3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3), c(2, 
    1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3), c(3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5), 2, c(3, 
    4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 5, 3), c(2, 6, 5, 3, 7, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 
    2), c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1), c(5, 5, 5, 
    3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 7), c(5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4), c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 5), c(3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5), c(5, 3, 2, 5, 
    3, 5, 3, 3, 3), c(2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5), c(3, 3, 3, 
    3, 5, 3, 3, 2, 3), c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2), c(3, 
    2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), c(3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3), 
        c(3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3), c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
        c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3), c(4, 4, 4, 4), c(10, 8, 10
        ), c(5, 5, 5), c(6, 4, 6), c(6, 6, 6, 10, 6), c(6, 10
        ), c(20, 10, 10, 10, 4, 10, 8), c(6, 6, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 
        6, 6), NULL, c(8, 8, 8), c(3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 6, 3), NULL, 
        NULL, c(6, 4, 6, 4), 1, c(3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1), c(5, 
        3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3), c(1, 2, 5, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 5, 2), 
        c(3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1), c(5, 6, 2, 6, 2), c(1, 6, 
        2, 6, 2, 3, 3, 3), c(5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 5), c(5, 5, 
        3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4), c(3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5), c(2, 2, 5, 
        3, 3, 5, 3, 4), c(2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 5, 2, 3), c(5, 
        2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4, 2), c(2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 
        3, 3), c(7, 5, 3, 2, 5, 9, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3)), Blackbird = list(
        c(3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5), c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 
        3, 3, 3), c(2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), c(5, 5, 11, 7, 3, 11, 
        15, 10, 5, 3), NULL, c(7, 2, 9, 3, 6, 3, 2, 3, 5), c(5, 
        2, 3, 1, 3, 5, 2, 1), c(3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 
        2), c(4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3), c(11, 7, 5, 
        4, 11, 11, 5), c(2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3), c(3, 3, 3, 
        3, 4, 4, 3, 3), c(3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2), c(5, 13, 
        3, 5, 7, 4, 3, 7), c(5, 8, 6, 5, 5, 6, 3, 5, 10), c(4, 
        3, 8, 4, 3, 6, 3), c(5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3), c(3, 3, 
        3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3), c(3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2), 
        c(5, 5, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1), c(5, 1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3), c(2, 
        3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3), c(1, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2), c(3, 6, 4, 
        2, 4), c(3, 3), c(2, 3), c(1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5), c(6, 6, 
        6, 6, 6, 4, 6), 2, c(4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2), c(1, 3, 3, 1, 
        2, 1, 3, 3, 2), 2, 3, c(4, 4, 6, 4), 2, c(2, 2, 5, 6, 
        4, 8), c(4, 3, 5, 5, 5), c(4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7), 
        c(6, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 1), c(3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 3, 5), 
        c(6, 7, 8, 7, 3, 8, 5, 10, 4, 5), c(6, 13, 3, 6, 8, 6, 
        14, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2), c(8, 8, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5), c(7, 
        4, 7, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4), c(6, 7, 5, 7, 6, 8, 4, 7, 6, 
        11), c(2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2), c(4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
        3, 4, 3, 2, 4), c(3, 8, 7, 7, 4, 6, 4, 7, 3, 3), c(4, 
        9, 7, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 5)), `Song Thrush` = list(c(1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 2), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 1, c(1, 1, 11), c(1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1), c(1, 1, 1, 1), 1, c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1), c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(2, 2, 1, 1), NULL, 1, 1, c(1, 
    1, 1), 1, c(1, 1, 2, 1), c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1), NULL, c(1, 
    1), NULL, NULL, NULL, c(1, 2, 2), NULL, 1, c(1, 1), NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, c(1, 1), 1, 1, c(1, 
        1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), NULL), Chaffinch = list(c(2, 
    1, 3, 3), c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1), c(1, 2), c(1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 1, 2), NULL, c(3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1), c(3, 1, 3, 
    2), NULL, c(5, 2, 2, 2, 4), c(2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 2, 2), c(5, 1, 3, 2, 3), c(2, 1, 1, 3), c(3, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 3, 1), c(2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 
    2, 3), c(2, 1, 2, 2, 2), c(4, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2), c(1, 3), c(3, 
    3, 1, 5, 1), c(2, 4, 5, 2, 2), c(2, 4, 2, 4, 1), c(6, 4, 
    4), c(5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4), c(6, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3), c(4, 
    4, 4), c(4, 2, 6, 2), c(7, 6, 8, 8, 8, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4), c(10, 
    6), c(2, 6, 6, 4), c(4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5), c(10, 10, 10), 
        NULL, c(2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4), NULL, c(6, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2), 
        c(4, 4, 2, 3, 10), c(1, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2), c(5, 
        4, 4, 2, 7, 6, 10, 2, 7, 2), c(2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 
        1, 1), c(13, 7, 3, 6, 13, 9, 5, 7, 7, 11), c(10, 7, 9, 
        7, 9, 17, 11, 8, 4), c(1, 3, 3), c(1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 
        2, 6, 4), c(5, 8, 6, 9, 9, 3, 11, 2, 5), c(2, 3, 3, 3, 
        2, 3), c(4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 3, 3), c(3, 2, 
        3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 5, 3), c(12, 5, 12, 8, 18, 
        6, 3, 4, 9, 15, 7, 10)), Starling = list(c(1, 3), 1, 
        3, c(5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 5), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(5, 
        9, 7, 5, 7, 7), NULL, c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), 3, NULL, NULL, 
        1, c(1, 3), c(1, 1), c(2, 2, 2, 2), c(5, 2, 1, 3, 7, 
        13, 1, 2, 2, 3), c(1, 2), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, c(1, 1), NULL, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        c(4, 12), NULL, c(2, 28, 9, 2, 3, 9), c(3, 7, 8, 2, 3, 
        12, 3), c(2, 1, 6, 9, 18), c(11, 1, 5, 30, 10), c(25, 
        9, 8, 39, 20, 18, 30), c(15, 10, 9, 27, 14, 15, 30, 30, 
        19, 12), c(3, 8, 14, 2, 21, 19, 35), c(13, 8, 9, 21, 
        9, 28, 1, 5, 16), c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 8, 1), c(6, 27, 6, 
        25, 16, 10, 3, 40, 5, 30), c(2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1), c(6, 
        4, 24, 6, 8, 7, 9, 10), c(17, 3, 1, 11, 5, 5, 2, 6, 6, 
        5, 2, 3), c(2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 14, 7, 5, 2, 6)), Goldfinch = list(
        c(1, 3, 5, 1, 1), NULL, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(2, 2, 
        2), c(3, 3, 3), c(2, 1), NULL, c(2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2), 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(2, 2, 2), 
        c(5, 3), 2, c(6, 10, 6, 6, 6, 8, 4), c(2, 6, 3), c(6, 
        4, 2), c(10, 10, 8, 8, 10, 10), c(1, 6, 6, 6, 1, 2, 6
        ), c(2, 2), c(2, 2, 4, 6), c(1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 6), 
        c(10, 8, 8), c(6, 6, 6, 2, 1), c(7, 8, 5, 8, 4), 10, 
        4, c(4, 3, 6, 4), 3, c(3, 5, 4, 2, 2, 6, 3), c(2, 4, 
        7, 6, 6, 6), c(10, 4, 6, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6), c(11, 15, 12, 
        9, 15, 8, 25), c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), c(23, 24, 12, 
        14, 20, 17, 13, 6, 18), c(18, 13, 19, 42, 10, 12, 21, 
        27, 7, 7), c(2, 2, 2, 1, 4), c(1, 5, 1, 7, 3, 3), c(6, 
        6, 18, 8, 6, 14, 16, 3, 7, 5, 4), c(8, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
        1, 3, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 2), c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1), 
        c(12, 3, 6, 9, 9, 4)), Brambling = list(c(2, 2), NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(2, 
        2, 2, 2), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(1, 2, 2, 1), NULL, NULL, 1, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, 1), Blackcap = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, c(1, 2, 2), NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        1, NULL, c(1, 1, 1), NULL, NULL, 1, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL), Jackdaw = list(
        2, c(1, 2), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(1, 
        1, 1, 2), NULL, c(1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1), 1, NULL, NULL, 
        c(6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), c(4, 2, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1), c(7, 
        2, 5), c(1, 1, 1, 1), 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(4, 
        4), NULL, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, c(2, 1), NULL, c(3, 5, 1, 2, 2), c(3, 2, 1, 1, 
        2, 4, 3, 3), c(3, 3, 6, 2, 9, 4, 10, 3, 2), c(6, 1, 1, 
        3, 4, 2, 3, 1), c(5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4), c(3, 2, 6, 5, 
        2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4), c(6, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 
        3), c(6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 8, 5, 4, 7, 6), c(5, 2, 3, 5, 4, 
        3, 3, 5, 2), c(3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2), c(3, 5, 9, 4, 
        3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 5), c(5, 1, 8, 6, 5, 6, 3, 3, 
        8, 6, 4), c(7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3), c(3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 
        2, 2, 7, 11, 3, 6)), Siskin = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(2, 2, 2), 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(1, 1), NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(2, 3), c(4, 
        2, 1, 2, 1), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        1, c(2, 2, 2), 1, NULL, c(3, 3), 2, c(4, 1, 2, 3), c(1, 
        4, 2), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2), c(3, 3), NULL, c(2, 2, 1), c(5, 
        1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), NULL), `Spotted Flycatcher` = list(
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, 2, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(1, 
        1), NULL, c(1, 1, 1), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)), row.names = c(NA, -50L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) # map_dbl
group_by(zz, year, Season, POSTCODE, LOC_ID) %>%
  summarize_all(~ map_dbl(., sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 50 x 25
#     year Season POSTCODE LOC_ID  Wren Dunnock `Blue Tit` `Pied/White Wag~ `Collared Dove` `Great Tit` Robin Greenfinch
#    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#  1  2010 Summer PE32 1TL LOC56~     1      10         13                0              62           8     5         30
#  2  2010 Winter PE32 1TL LOC56~     4      15         16                4              48          10    11         11
#  3  2011 Spring PE32 1TL LOC56~     0       8         10                1              25          10    18         16
#  4  2011 Summer PE32 1TL LOC56~     0      18         17                0              52          11     7         17
#  5  2011 Winter PE32 1TL LOC56~     2       5         22                1              51          10    13          7
#  6  2012 Autumn PE32 1TL LOC56~     2       6         28                1              24          18     4          9
#  7  2012 Winter PE32 1TL LOC56~     4      10         18                6              43          16     6         22
#  8  2013 Winter PE32 1TL LOC56~     2       6         20                2              23           8     5         14
#  9  2014 Autumn NR15 1TS LOC11~     0       1         30                0               1           6     6          4
# 10  2014 Summer NR15 1TS LOC11~     0       2         30                0               0          14     1          4
# # ... with 40 more rows, and 13 more variables: `House Sparrow` <dbl>, `Coal Tit` <dbl>, Woodpigeon <dbl>,
# #   Blackbird <dbl>, `Song Thrush` <dbl>, Chaffinch <dbl>, Starling <dbl>, Goldfinch <dbl>, Brambling <dbl>,
# #   Blackcap <dbl>, Jackdaw <dbl>, Siskin <dbl>, `Spotted Flycatcher` <dbl>
```

(You can do it without `purrr::map_dbl`, just use `sapply` in its place.)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `summarise` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
zz %>% 
    group_by(year, Season, POSTCODE, LOC_ID) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ map_dbl(., sum, na.rm = TRUE)))
```